# Mongoose and Model Connections

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get my head around how mongoose uses it's connection. At the moment I have:

```
// Datastore.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    conn = mongoose.createConnection();

...

conn.open(host, database, port, options, callback); // Opens connection


// Model.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({...})
module.exports = exports = mongoose.model('MyModel', Schema);


// Controller.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel'); // Retrieves the model ok

MyModel.find({}, function(err, docs){
   if(err){} //
   console.log(docs); // Does not work
});
```

However this doesn't work... it only works if somehow I pass the connection across like so:

```
// Datastore.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    conn = mongoose.createConnection();

...

conn.open(host, database, port, options, callback); //

mongoose.set('db', conn);


// Controller.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.get('db');

var MyModel = db.model('MyModel'); // Retrieve the model using the connection instance

MyModel.find({}, function(err, docs){
   if(err){} //
   console.log(docs); // Works
});
```

I think I'm approaching this in the wrong way... should the first approach work, and I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easiest to just open the default connection pool that's shared by all your mongoose calls:

```
// Datastore.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'dbname');
```

Then in all your other files access the pool using `mongoose.model(...)`.

Comment: Thanks - how do I go about setting up the default connection?

Comment: That's what the `mongoose.connect` call does.  I added the typical parameters.

Comment: Thank you - I'm not sure the difference between this, and the method I was using and why the two technique differ in the models accessing the connection.

Comment: @leepowell If you use your original method, you'd need to pass around `conn` everywhere and call `conn.model` instead of `mongoose.model`.

Comment: this no longer works if you use your model in more than one place. https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1249

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/) it says:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');
```

Perhaps you need to put your connection details in for the create Connection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');
```

Comment: The connection part is fine, I have it connecting successfully. Using 'open' just defers the timing of the connection taking place.